# Patio door molding replacement

Tags: trim, sliding-glass-door

Trying to repair a patio sliding door, and this edge molding is breaking loose. I've temporarily fixed it with hot glue, but would like to replace it.

It's a pretty hard plastic, and brittle now that it's 27 years old. However, I don't know what the name of this molding piece is, so I'm having trouble finding a replacement. Here's a picture of it. As you can see, it's split at the bottom. Can you tell me what this is called?

[image]

Comment: Weather stripping instead of trim.  Do not know how specific it is to that make of door, but might find a replacement if a piece is taken to a hardware store.

Comment: it looks like custom made pice, who is the manufacturer

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. Certainly not a custom made house. Site condo, built in 1995.